# PHP array_reduce(): getting an error 'invalid function name'

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, mongodb

I got an error while using array_reduce(). I think syntax is correct.
This function returns sum of numbers in an array.

```
function sum($el1, $el2){
    if(!isset($return_sum))
        $return_sum = 0;
    $return_sum = $return_sum + ($el1+$el2);
    return $return_sum;
}
$sum = array_reduce($months_data, 'sum');
```

```
Error: array_reduce() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'sum' not found or invalid function name.
```

**$months_data**:

```
Array
(
[201905] => 2
[201906] => 7
[201907] => 1
[201908] => 6
[201909] => 2
[201911] => 14
[201912] => 6
[202001] => 5
[202002] => 8
[202003] => 7
)
```

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://3v4l.org/WGOGv

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce it, just as a test - try changing the name and see if that changes anything (Just a note not sure why you use `if(!isset($return_sum))` as it will not be set)

Comment: Where you use sum function?

Comment: `array_sum($months_data)` does the same.

Comment: @NigelRen I tried by changing names. but getting same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your function `sum`, is inside a class, i.e. its the class's method. You should try this:

```
$sum = array_reduce($months_data, array($this,"sum"));
```

Comment: And if your assumption is incorrect?

Comment: @u_mulder I ran into a similar problem sometime back, it's a common error.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Your assumption is correct :)